# How to check if redis server is running using Predis library in PHP

Tags: php, exception, redis, predis

I am integrating Redis cache with one of my website, I am using Predis as client side. I have created a static class for initializing.

I need to check if the redis server is running or not.

I have tried so many thins but it did not work, it is not able to catch the exception.

My code is

```
public static function checkRedisConnection()
{
    self::initialize();
    $client = new Predis\Client();
    try
    {
        $client->connect();
    }
    catch (Predis\Network\ConnectionException $exception)
    {
        exit("whoops, couldn't connect to the remote redis instance!");
    }

    $client->info();
}
```

The above function in a class is not able to catch the error, instead it is showing the error on whole site.

What to do in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your try / catch block cannot intercept the exception for a very simple reason: the class `Predis\Network\ConnectionException` doesn't exist, the correct one is `Predis\Connection\ConnectionException` ([see also here](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/0e17edbefb50c6cbd1acc4a6f6ef06399deb1af2/FAQ.md#how-can-i-force-predis-to-connect-to-redis-before-sending-any-command))

Comment: Thanks, Yes you are correct, I used catch (Predis\Connection\ConnectionException $exception)